Linux open suse leap countervector off timer
I'm Installed: linux open suse leap ~15. Something wrong when after turn off and if press: ctrl+esc it will shows timer: countervector.
1 min .30 sec...
...
1 min .29 sec...
1 min .28 sec......

and just then turn off...
Need help.
I try recovering but nothing any effects (may be it my recover snapshot problem. It not automatically marked)

It's unclear what the issue is.  Is it that you see the countdown timer, or is it that the system shuts down when you press Ctrl+Esc?

It's countdown  timer It can appear when ctrl+esc not onlly pressing but It hidden and application freezes and died died after switch off system/

A countdown timer at system shutdown usually means some service did not stop immediately when systemd asked it to stop. systemd will then display a timer and wait for a time (1 min 30 sec by default): if the service has not stopped in that time, systemd will usually force that service to stop (configurable). So, the timer being displayed, then the system turning off before the timer reached 0 is usually a good thing: it means the service stopped in a controlled fashion and did not need to be killed with extreme force by systemd.

@telcoM Where is located systemd It not found in my comp? Help me please

It's at /usr/lib/systemd/systemd in SuSE SLES 15, probably the same path in OpenSuSE. See also ps -fp 1 to find it: systemd should be running as process ID 1. If that is not true, either your system is not OpenSuSE Leap 15, or it has been extensively modified.

Full Instruction please in Completely Answer.
